# MPI c++ ring topology sends and receives different values while passing only the same value?

Tags: c++, mpi

I am just learning the ring topology MPI in c++. I wrote a c++ script to calculate 10 dimensional Monte carlo integration and to calculate its mean and local max value. My goal is to pass each proessors' local max value through the "ring".

Now, I still didn't figure out how to store the max values generated from different processors in runtime in an array, so I compiled and executed the code once, and manually made an array with the values.

Next I want to pass each of the array values through the ring, and eventually calculate the global maxima. 
Now I m just experimenting with passing the first array value, and I see the processors send the same value but receive different ones. I honestly don't know if c++ use the MPI library differently and I followed an online tutorial for MPI with C and was kind of using the same structure as C does  in my c++ code.

I am sharing the code here.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cmath>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>
#include <mpi.h>
using namespace std;


//define multivariate function F(x1, x2, ...xk)            

double f(double x[], int n)
{
    double y;
    int j;
    y = 0.0;

    for (j = 0; j < n-1; j = j+1)
      {
         y = y + exp(-pow((1-x[j]),2)-100*(pow((x[j+1] - pow(x[j],2)),2)));

      }     

    y = y;
    return y;
}

//define function for Monte Carlo Multidimensional integration

double int_mcnd(double(*fn)(double[],int),double a[], double b[], int n, int m)

{
    double r, x[n], v;
    int i, j;
    r = 0.0;
    v = 1.0;
    // initial seed value (use system time) 
    //srand(time(NULL)); 


    // step 1: calculate the common factor V
    for (j = 0; j < n; j = j+1)
      {
         v = v*(b[j]-a[j]);
      } 

    // step 2: integration
    for (i = 1; i <= m; i=i+1)
    {
        // calculate random x[] points
        for (j = 0; j < n; j = j+1)
        {
            x[j] = a[j] +  (rand()) /( (RAND_MAX/(b[j]-a[j])));
        }         
        r = r + fn(x,n);
    }
    r = r*v/m;

    return r;
}




double f(double[], int);
double int_mcnd(double(*)(double[],int), double[], double[], int, int); 



int main(int argc, char **argv)
{    

    int rank, size;

    MPI_Init (&argc, &argv);      // initializes MPI
    MPI_Comm_rank (MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank); // get current MPI-process ID. O, 1, ...
    MPI_Comm_size (MPI_COMM_WORLD, &size); // get the total number of processes


    /* define how many integrals */
    const int n = 10;       

    double b[n] = {5.0, 5.0, 5.0, 5.0, 5.0, 5.0, 5.0, 5.0, 5.0,5.0};                    
    double a[n] = {-5.0, -5.0, -5.0, -5.0, -5.0, -5.0, -5.0, -5.0, -5.0,-5.0};  

    double result, mean;
    int m;

    const unsigned int N = 5;
    double max = -1;


    cout.precision(6);
    cout.setf(ios::fixed | ios::showpoint); 


    srand(time(NULL) * rank);  // each MPI process gets a unique seed

    m = 4;                // initial number of intervals

    // convert command-line input to N = number of points
    //N = atoi( argv[1] );


    for (unsigned int  i=0; i <=N; i++)
    {
        result = int_mcnd(f, a, b, n, m);
        mean = result/(pow(10,10));

        if( mean > max) 
        {
         max = mean;
        }
        //cout << setw(10)  << m << setw(10) << max << setw(10) << mean << setw(10) << rank << setw(10) << size <<endl;
        m = m*4; 
    }

    //cout << setw(30)  << m << setw(30) << result << setw(30) << mean <<endl; 
    printf("Process %d of %d mean = %1.5e\n and local max = %1.5e\n", rank, size, mean, max );


    double max_store[4] = {4.43095e-02, 5.76586e-02, 3.15962e-02, 4.23079e-02}; 

    double send_junk = max_store[0];
    double rec_junk;
    MPI_Status status;


  // This next if-statment implemeents the ring topology
  // the last process ID is size-1, so the ring topology is: 0->1, 1->2, ... size-1->0
  // rank 0 starts the chain of events by passing to rank 1
  if(rank==0) {
    // only the process with rank ID = 0 will be in this block of code.
    MPI_Send(&send_junk, 1, MPI_INT, 1, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD); //  send data to process 1
    MPI_Recv(&rec_junk, 1, MPI_INT, size-1, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status); // receive data from process size-1
  }
  else if( rank == size-1) { 
    MPI_Recv(&rec_junk, 1, MPI_INT, rank-1, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status); // recieve data from process rank-1 (it "left" neighbor")
    MPI_Send(&send_junk, 1, MPI_INT, 0, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD); // send data to its "right neighbor", rank 0
  }
  else {
    MPI_Recv(&rec_junk, 1, MPI_INT, rank-1, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status); // recieve data from process rank-1 (it "left" neighbor")
    MPI_Send(&send_junk, 1, MPI_INT, rank+1, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD); // send data to its "right neighbor" (rank+1)
  }
  printf("Process %d send %1.5e\n and recieved %1.5e\n", rank, send_junk, rec_junk ); 


  MPI_Finalize(); // programs should always perform a "graceful" shutdown
    return 0;
}
```

I compiled with:

```
mpiCC -std=c++11 -o hg test_code.cpp
mpirun -np 4 ./hg
```

The output looks like this with different mean amd max of course but I am worried about send and recvd values for now:

```
Process 2 of 4 mean = 2.81817e-02
 and local max = 5.61707e-02
Process 0 of 4 mean = 2.59220e-02
 and local max = 4.43095e-02
Process 3 of 4 mean = 2.21734e-02
 and local max = 4.30539e-02
Process 1 of 4 mean = 2.87403e-02
 and local max = 6.58530e-02
Process 1 send 4.43095e-02
 and recieved 2.22181e-315
Process 2 send 4.43095e-02
 and recieved 6.90945e-310
Process 3 send 4.43095e-02
 and recieved 6.93704e-310
Process 0 send 4.43095e-02
 and recieved 6.89842e-310
```

I think I am messing up with the MPI usage in C and c++, I would appreciate any suggestion, also I didn't see any good c++ MPI tutorials over internet, so a good modified example of my code or tutorial link will  be very helpful. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The third argument of `MPI_Recv` and `MPI_Send` is the data type. Now you are sending an `double` but you set data type to `MPI_INT`. In most systems `int` are 4 bytes and `double` are 8 bytes, hence half of the bytes in the `rec_junk` is uninitialized.

To fix it just change `MPI_INT` to `MPI_DOUBLE` in all the calls of `MPI_Recv` and `MPI_Send`.